# Ansible how restart service one after one on different hosts

Tags: ansible

Hy every one !
pls help .
I have 3 server. Each of them have one systemd service. I need reboot this service by one.
So after i reboot service on host 1 , and this service is up ( i can check tcp port), i need reboot service on host 2 and so on.
How i can do it with ansible

Now i have such playbook:

```
---
- name: Install business service
  hosts: business
  vars:
    app_name: "e-service"
    app: "{{ app_name }}-{{ tag }}.war"
    app_service: "{{ app_name }}.service"
    app_bootstrap: "{{ app_name }}_bootstrap.yml"
    app_folder: "{{ eps_client_dir }}/{{ app_name }}"
    archive_folder: "{{ app_folder }}/archives/arch_{{ansible_date_time.date}}_{{ansible_date_time.hour}}_{{ansible_date_time.minute}}"
    app_distrib_dir: "{{ eps_distrib_dir }}/{{ app_name }}"
    app_dependencies: "{{ app_distrib_dir }}/dependencies.tgz"

  tasks:

   - name: Copy app {{ app }}  to {{ app_folder }}
    copy:
     src: "{{ app_distrib_dir }}/{{ app }}"
     dest: "{{ app_folder }}/{{ app }}"
     group: ps_group
     owner: ps
     mode: 0644
    notify:
       - restart app

  - name: Copy service setting to /etc/systemd/system/{{app_service}}
    template:
     src: "{{ app_distrib_dir }}/{{ app_service }}"
     dest: /etc/systemd/system/{{ app_service }}
     mode: 0644
    notify:
       - restart app


  - name: Start service {{ app }}
    systemd:
     daemon-reload: yes
     name: "{{ app_service }}"
     state: started
     enabled: true

  handlers:
    - name: restart app
      systemd:
        daemon-reload: yes
        name: "{{ app_service }}"
        state: restarted
        enabled: true
```

and all service restart at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try serial and max_fail_percentage, max_fail_percentage value is percent of the whole number of your hosts, if server 1 failed, then the rest server will not run,

```
---
- name: Install eps-business service
  hosts: business
  serial: 1
  max_fail_percentage: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
---
- name: Install eps-business service
  hosts: business
  serial: 1
```

> By default, Ansible will try to manage all of the machines referenced in a play in parallel. For a rolling update use case, you can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the serial keyword

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

create a script that reboots your service and then add a loop that will check whether the service is up or not and once it is executed successfully based on the status it has returned you can go for the next service.